# Prove that the series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{2n}\over n^2+x^{2n}}$ converges uniformly in $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{2n}\over n^2+x^{2n}}$$

I want to show that the series is uniformly convergent in $[-1,1]$.

> **Theorem**: A series of functions $\sum f_n$ will converge uniformly on $[a,b]$ if there exist a convergent $\sum M_n$ of positive numbers
>   such that for all $x\in [a,b]$ $$|f_n(x)|\le M_n$$ for all $n$.

Attempt:

For $x\in [-1,1]\quad$ $|x^{2n}|\le 1\tag{1}$.

Recall,

> Reverse Triangle Inequality \begin{equation*} ||x|-|y||\le|x+y|.
>  \end{equation*}

So $n^2-|x^{2n}|\le|n^2+x^{2n}|$ Therefore we have $n^2-1\le |x^{2n}+n^2|\tag{2}$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $$|f_n(x)|\le {1\over n^2-1}$$

Let $a_n=1/n^2$, then ${M_n\over a_n}={n^2\over n^2-1}={1\over 1-{1\over n^2}}$ Therefor by Limit form comparison test, $\sum M_n$ converges.

The result follows.

---

Is this series uniformly convergent only in $[-1,1]$ and to what function it converges?

Edits: For $|x|>1$,

Divide by $|x|^{2n}$, we get $${1\over 1+{n^2\over |x|^{2n}}}$$. Since exponential grows faster than $n^2$ the expression goes to $1$ as $n\to \infty$

Therefore series diverges for $|x|>1$

Comment: Does the summand go to zero for $x>1$, as $n $ goes to infinity?

Comment: @AnyAD Thanks I understand it now.  I have edited the post to show the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Define $$f_n(x)={x^{2n}\over n^2+x^{2n}}$$In the interval $[-1,1]$ we have $0\le x^{2n}\le 1$ therefore $$|f_n(x)|=f_n(x)\le {1\over n^2+1}$$Now define $M_n={1\over n^2+1}$. Obviously the series $\sum M_n$ is convergent because$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n^2+1}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n^2}={\pi^2\over 6}$$and $$|f_n(x)|\le M_n$$which means that the sequence of $\{M_n\}$ fulfills the conditions of the theorem and using that theorem, we have proved what we wanted.

Comment: I think you want $f_n(x)\le \frac{1}{n^2}.$

Comment: Also ${1\over n^2}$ is another possibility for $M_n$ since ${1\over n^2+1}<{1\over n^2}$

Comment: But why do you say $$f_n(x)\le {1\over n^2+1}?$$

Comment: I'm just looking for some $M_n$ so that the conditions of the theorem hold i.e. $$|f_n(x)|\le M_n$$since we have $$|f_n(x)|\le {1\over n^2}$$ we can arbitrarily choose $M_n={1\over n^2+1}$

Comment: But $1/(n^2+1)<1/n^2.$

Comment: Question: is it different to choose $M_n={1\over n^2}$ rather than $M_n={1\over n^2+1}$?

Comment: You seem to be saying that if $f_n\le 1/n^2,$ then $f_n\le 1/(n^2+1).$

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify it more. Hope it is enlightened enough now...

Comment: I believe zhw's comments are motivated by the "standard" estimation $\frac{x^{2n}}{n^2+x^{2n}} \le \frac{1}{n^2+x^{2n}} \le \frac{1}{n^2+0}$. This is what you really use when considering $\sum M_n$. However, also $f_n(x) \le \frac{1}{n^2+1}$ is true, although it requires a little more effort to verify it. Computing $f'_n(x)$ we see that $f_n$ is increasing on $[0,1]$ which means that it attains its maximum in the points $\pm1$.

Comment: I think even differentiation is not needed but I tried to answer the question as simple as possible.

Comment: How do you show $f_n(x) \le {1\over n^2+1}$?

Comment: Because $y\over n^2+y$ is strictly increasing for $y\ge0$. Now just simply substitute $y=x^{2n}$

Comment: You are right, that can be easily shown without considering $f'_n(x)$!

Comment: Quite right!...